# Is $currentDate strictly increasing in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, time, optimistic-locking

We're using the `$currentDate` operator to set a field for concurrency control. The expected value of this field is then provided as a filter whilst updating to ensure no update has happened concurrently. With multiple nodes is it guaranteed that the operator will always set increasing values? Or is there the potential to set the same value twice?

Comment: Nit-pick: a "monotonically increasing" function can actually return the same values. What you are looking for is a "strictly increasing" function.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @AurelBílý! I've changed the title. Perhaps this will help my search for the answer

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by multiple nodes -- are you referring to a sharded cluster deployment or having a number of application servers?

Comment: @Stennie a replica set

Comment: The question is whether updating the system time (e.g. due to time sync service) we can get the time to go back a few seconds/minutes.

Comment: @DrorHarari exactly. We assumed that it probably was **not** strictly increasing and just used an integer counter to be safe.